# Как через код C# динамически добавить стили для textBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется элемент:

```
<TextBox
                materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="x1"
                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Width="40" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
```

При загрузке формы мне необходимо создать n таких элементов. Использую MaterialDesingToolkit. Как при загрузке формы привязать к нему стиль `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"` через код C#?

Comment: `Как при загрузке формы привязать к нему стиль` - зачем? Научитесь использовать привязки! Почитайте про XAML, а также про подход MVVM.

Comment: На первой форме пользователь вводит некоторое число. От этого числа зависит количество текстовых полей, которое будет создано при загрузке второй формы. И мне нужно именно ЭТО текстовое поле именно с ЭТИМ стилем. Я в WPF новичок и только начинаю во всё это углубляться. На данном этапе меня интересует именно тот вопрос, который я задал. Реально ли это вообще сделать.

Comment: Ну так делайте int свойство, к которому будете привязывать текстовое поле, на его основе генерируйте коллекцию, которая также будет привязана куда надо. Стиль, для этого в WPF есть например `DataTemplate`, через который можно на любой тип объекта задать нужный вид, вам достаточно этот тип добавить в коллекцию и WPF сам, за вас, назначит нужный тип. `Я в WPF новичок и только начинаю во всё это углубляться.` - Это я прекрасно понимаю, но и вы ведь должны понимать, что учить надо сразу правильные вещи, а не костыли, да? `Реально ли это вообще сделать` - да, реально `объект.Style = стиль;`.